# How to correctly prototype C functions

Tags: c

I'm learning the concept of prototyping in C, however I'm struggling with the correct syntax.  I'm writing a function to strip all non-alphbetic characters from a c-string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char[30] clean(char[30] );

int main()
{
    char word[30] = "hello";
    char cleanWord[30];
    cleanWord = clean(word);
    return 0;
}


char[30] clean(char word[30])
{
    char cleanWord[30];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(word);i++)
        if ( isalpha(word[i]) )
            cleanWord[i]=word[i];

    cleanWord[i]='\0';

    return cleanWord;
}
```

How do I correctly prototype the function?  What are the other syntax errors that are preventing my program from compiling?

Comment: Just for future reference: It helps when you get a compiler error when you mention that, and post the **exact** error message you're getting. (This question is pretty easy to figure out, but future ones might not be that clear.) Also, adding a vague "What are the other possible errors I might get from this code?" is not a specific question, and expecting us to review all of your code to predict other problems you might have is not realistic or appropriate, as SO is for specific questions about actual problems you're experiencing now. It also helps to know which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not with function prototyping (aka forward declaration).  You just can't return an array from a function in C.  Nor can you assign to an array variable.  You need to make a couple of changes to get things working.  One option:

1. change `char cleanWord[30]` in `main` to be `char * cleanWord`.
2. change the signature of `clean` to `char *clean(char word[30])`
3. use `malloc` to allocate a destnation buffer inside `clean`
4. return a pointer to that new buffer
5. free the buffer in `main`

And another:

1. change the signature of `clean` to `void clean(char word[30], char cleanWord[30])`
2. operate on the passed-in pointer rather than a local array in `clean`
3. change the call in `main` to be `clean(word, cleanWord)`.

Answer (score 3):

As Carl Norum said, you can't return an array.  Instead, what you tend to do is supply the output:

```
void clean( const char word[30], char cleanWord[30] )
{
}
```

And you should remove the locally-scoped array from that function.

You will find that the function does not work correctly, because you only have one iterator `i`.  That means if a character is not an alpha, you will skip over a position in the output array.  You will need a second iterator that is incremented only when you add a character to `cleanWord`.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of notes (was a bit late with writing up an answer, seems I've been beaten to them by the others )

1. C cannot return local (stack) objects, if you want to return an array from a function you have to `malloc` it
2. Even if you declare an array argument as `(char arr[30])`, `(char* arr)` is just as valid as arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments to functions. Also, you won't be able to get the size correctly of such arrays by using `sizeof`. Even though it's 30, on my machine it returns 4 for `word` in `clean`, which is the size of the pointer for it.
3. You are missing an include, `isalpha` is part of `ctype.h`

I've updated your code, hopefully I've guessed your intentions correctly:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc and free */
#include <string.h> /* for strlen */
#include <ctype.h>  /* for isalpha */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf */

/* Function declaration */
char* clean(char word[30]);

/* your 'main()' would now look like this: */
int main()
{
    char word[30] = "hel1lo1";

    char* cleanWord;

    cleanWord = clean(word);

    printf("%s\n", cleanWord);

    free(cleanWord);

    return 0;
}

/* Function definition */
char* clean(char word[30])
{
    char* cleanWord = malloc(30);   /* allocating dynamically an array of 30 chars, 
                                     * no need to use sizeof here as char is 
                                     * guaranteed to be 1 by the standard 
                                     */

    unsigned int i, j = 0; /* let's fix the problem with non-alpha chars already pointed out */

    for (i = 0; i < (strlen(word)); i++)
        if (isalpha(word[i]))
            cleanWord[j++] = word[i]; 


    cleanWord[j] = '\0';

    return cleanWord; 
    /* return a pointer to the malloc`ed array, don't forget to free it after you're done with it */
}
```